# Change the config values in Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

I have Config.ini file with the content

```
[episode]
unlock = false;
```

I want to change the value from the controller like

```
$this->config['episode'] = array('unlock' => true);
```

**OR**

```
$this->config->episode->unlock = true;
```

I have this on my loader file

```
$di->set('config', function() use($config){
   return $config;
});
```

Comment: If you were to change the values, the new values wouldn't persist between requests. Why do you want to do this? I suspect it can be accomplished another way

Comment: You can store config in some DBs like mysql or redis or etc, so you can access the changed value in later requests.

Comment: i did from database as soon as i know the changes won't persist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to get the config from your DI container first, then you can change values as much as you like.

```
$config = $this->di->get('config');
$config['episode'] = array('unlock' => true);
```

As mentioned in the comments, this works, but doesn't make that much sense, because the new value will not persist between requests.

Comment: okay, then changes to config variable will exist as far as the execution exists right?

i thought, if the changes will appear in the file, like filewrite!

Comment: If you'd like persistent configuration that's changeable, Config is not the right tool. It merely provides read-only access to native arrays, .ini Files or - if you use the incubator package - YAML configuration files. For a writable configuration setup, I would suggest creating a model, so you can read and write changes to your database.